# Bayesian filtering and Gaussian Integrals: change the variable

Tags: stochastic-integrals, bayesian, gaussian-integral

Suppose ${{\bf{\xi }}\sim N({\bf{0}},{\bf{I}})}$, then 
$${\bf{x}} = {\bf{\hat x}} + {{\bf{P}}^{{1 \mathord{\left/
 {\vphantom {1 2}} \right.
 } 2}}}{\bf{\xi }}$$
where ${\bf{P}}^{{1 \mathord{\left/
 {\vphantom {1 2}} \right.
 2}}}$ is a lower triangle matrix or the Cholesky decomposition of $\bf{P}$ such that ${{\bf{P}}^{\frac{1}{2}}}{({{\bf{P}}^{\frac{1}{2}}})^T} = {\bf{P}}$.

By changing the variable of integration from $x$ to $\xi$ we must get [(1)](https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/abs/10.1002/wics.1215)

$$\int_{{{\bf{x}}_1}}^{{{\bf{x}}_2}} {{\bf{g}}({\bf{x}})N({\bf{x}};{\bf{\hat x}},{\bf{P}})} d{\bf{x}} = \int_{_{{\bf{\xi }}1}}^{{{\bf{\xi }}_2}} {{\bf{g}}({\bf{\hat x}} + {{\bf{P}}^{\frac{1}{2}}}{\bf{\xi }})N({\bf{\xi }};{\bf{0}},{\bf{I}})} d{\bf{\xi }}$$.

However I think the correct substutaion is
$$\begin{array}{l}
{\bf{x}} = {\bf{\hat x}} + {{\bf{P}}^{\frac{1}{2}}}{\bf{\xi }} \to d{\bf{x}} = d({{\bf{P}}^{\frac{1}{2}}}{\bf{\xi }}) = d{\bf{\xi }}{{\bf{P}}^{\frac{1}{2}}} = {({{\bf{P}}^{\frac{1}{2}}})^T}d{\bf{\xi }}\\
\int_{{{\bf{x}}_1}}^{{{\bf{x}}_2}} {{\bf{g}}({\bf{x}})N({\bf{x}};{\bf{\hat x}},{\bf{P}})} d{\bf{x}}\mathop  = \limits^{{\bf{x}} = {\bf{\hat x}} + {{\bf{P}}^{\frac{1}{2}}}{\bf{\xi }}} \int_{_{{\bf{\xi }}1}}^{{{\bf{\xi }}_2}} {{\bf{g}}({\bf{\hat x}} + {{\bf{P}}^{\frac{1}{2}}}{\bf{\xi }})N({\bf{\xi }};{\bf{0}},{\bf{I}})} \underbrace {{{({{\bf{P}}^{\frac{1}{2}}})}^T}}_{{\rm{???}}}d{\bf{\xi }}
\end{array}$$
So, what will happen to the term ${{{({{\bf{P}}^{\frac{1}{2}}})}^T}}$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since we are doing a change of variables in more than 1 dimension, it is true that

$$d\mathbf{x}=J(\mathbf{x}, \mathbf{\xi})d\mathbf{\xi}$$

where $J$ is the jacobian determinant of the transformation:

$$J=|\det(\frac{\partial x_i}{\partial \xi_j})|$$

In your case

$$\frac{\partial x_i}{\partial \xi_j}=P^{1/2}_{ij}$$

and thus $J=|\det(P^{1/2})|=\sqrt{\det(P)}$, which in turn cancels with the normalization of the multivariate Gaussian.

EDIT:

The multivariate normal distribution is given by the formula:

$$N(\mathbf{x},\mathbf{y},\mathbf{P})=\frac{1}{\sqrt{(2\pi)^n \det\mathbf{P}}}\exp(-(\mathbf{x-y})^T\mathbf{P}^{-1}(\mathbf{x-y}))$$

The Jacobian cancels the denominator to produce the formula for $N(\mathbf{x,0,I})=\frac{1}{(2\pi)^{n/2}}e^{-|\mathbf{x-y}|^2}$ after the change of variables.

Comment: Thank you  for answer. Cloud you please explain this mathematically: "_which in turn cancels with the normalization of the multivariate Gaussian_"?

Comment: I edited to explain what I meant. :)